# Chart update everytime on Loading second array : Highcharts, Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, highcharts

So, What I have is a condition in a MySQL to show the first 1000 data points first and then the other 2000 datapoints after that in Highcharts.

```
if lastindex==0:
            cur.execute("SELECT data,value FROM table where id<1001")
        else:
            cur.execute("SELECT data,value FROM table where id>1001 and id<3000")
        data = cur.fetchall()  
//python Code to fetch SQL data
```

Now what I am doing is that I am rendering that data into the Highcharts, the data is being rendered. but the problem arises that after showing the first 1000 data points, the Highcharts value starts from `0` and then shows the other 2000 points

the data is not displaying continuously as it should plot the send array data just after the end of the first data.

I think the Highcharts is being called Twice, What can I do to append the 2nd set of data to the first set without reloading the whole chart.

Here's a snip of my Highchart's js

```
Highcharts.chart("chartcontainer", {
                chart: {
                    type: 'line',
                    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                    marginRight: 10,
                    events: {
                        load: function() {

                            var series = this.series[0],
                                chart = this;

                            setInterval(function() {

                      //some logic regarding the chart
                       //..
                        v = {
                                                y: y,
                                                x: x
                                            };

                    console.log("V value", v);
                    series.addSeries(v, false, true);
                    counter++;
                    localcounter++;                                 
                }   else
                {

                    oldcounter=counter;
                    flagToreload=1;
                                    }
                            }, 1000/130);

                            setInterval(function() {
                                chart.redraw(false);
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    }
                },

                time: {
                    useUTC: false
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Live random data'
                },
                xAxis: {

                    type: 'Value',

                    gridLineWidth: 1

                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }],
                    gridLineWidth: 1
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                    animation: false,
                    name: 'Random data',
                    data: (function() {
                        // generate an array of random data
                        var data = [],
                            time = counter,
                            i;

                        for (i = -1000; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                            data.push([
                                counter,
                                null
                        ]);


                        }
                        return data;
                    }())
                }]
            });
```

What I want is just to append the event data rather than loading the whole chart.

How can I reload a particular Highchart value without reloading the whole chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about updating the current series with new data, which will be an array of old data merged with the new one?

```
  chart: {
    events: {
        load(){
             let chart = this,
                 currentSeries = chart.series[0],
             newData;
             newData = [...currentSeries.userOptions.data, ...data1]

                setTimeout(()=> {
                chart.series[0].update({
                data: newData
              })
            }, 5000)
      }
    }
  },
```

See the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qdmsfon0/)

Comment: what If I want to define chart only once and load the events on data update dynamically, so that my chart does not starts from 0 again

Comment: You can use the setInterval functionality except the set Timeout and do a similar thing. The chart starts from 0. I don't know how many times you would like to trigger this operation, but you should think about some condition also, because to many points can break your chart. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mwj1xg7p/